# item.(Tweet) in Golang language, What does it mean?

Tags: go

I found the following code in Golang language

```
item.(Tweet)
```

I already know that there is a method for each variable. But I don't know the code above. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is probably type assertions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it really saves my time.

Comment: You could save even more time by taking [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) for a decent introduction to the language.

Comment: Duplicate. The 20ths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492868/i-do-not-understand-this-syntax)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

> A type assertion provides access to an **interface** value's underlying concrete value.

Example:

```
var num interface{} = 5
var numActual int = num.(int)

fmt.Println(numActual)
```

On code above, `num` is a variable whom type is `interface{}`. It can hold any kind of value, but in example above it's storing a numeric int data, `5`.

To get the underlying concrete value from `num`, simply add `.(type)` on the end of the variable.

```
num.(int)
```

You can check whether an `interface{}` variable is convertible into certain type or not, by checking the 2nd return value of the statement. Example:

```
if actual, ok := num.(string); !ok {
    fmt.Println("num is not string")
    fmt.Println("it's a number data with value is", actual)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Should change the `ok` with `!ok` for better clarity. I can't edit it cause its only 1 character changes.